# button color doesnt change once clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button called `Button1`, and I have the following code-behind:

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EasyRozMoney_ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spTaskPerformed", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TaskId", lblTaskId.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Session["Email"].ToString());
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Button1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    Button1.Enabled = false;
    lblTaskPerformed.Text = "Task Completed Successfully.";
}
```

Everything else works fine.The button gets disabled too but it doesn't change its background color. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do it in JavaScript rather than C#.

Comment: Why would you color your button red on a successful operation?

Comment: too bad.i dont know javascript.And also i noticed that when i click back,the button is enabled again.

Comment: @DamienJoe Well,its just to show that this task is performed already.I just want to throw a signal.

Comment: @Mash Red always signals danger or something that has failed!

Comment: [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/9924/change-the-background-color-of-a-button-with-javascript.aspx) provides the method to change button color using JavaScript

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i understand.this is just in testing mode right now.I am just curious about the button not changing its color

Comment: What about the button getting enabled again after the click the back button.ant it stay disabled?

Comment: @Mash, is there anything else that tries to set the `BackColor` property on `Button1`?

Comment: @KyleMit - Yes.This:
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" style="color: #FFFFFF; font-weight: 700; background-color: #CC6600" Width="100px" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

Comment: @Mosh, the inline style is what is messing this up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update:

The inline style on your button is preventing the background color from showing up.

Here's why:

Consider the following ASPX code:

```html
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" Text="Click Me!" 
            style="background-color: yellow;"/>
```

This will render the following HTML:

```html
<input type="submit" id="MainContent_Button1" value="Click Me!" 
       style="background-color: yellow;">
```

When we add a `BackColor` in the code behind, it *prepends* an inline style into the element's style attribute. Which produces this HTML:

```html
<input type="submit" id="MainContent_Button1" value="Click Me!" 
       style="background-color:Red;background-color: yellow;">
```

So it inserts the red color, but then the original color immediately overrides it.

To solve this, in your ASPX, use the `BackColor` property instead of using the `background-color` inline style tag. Like this:

```html
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            BackColor="#CC6600" style="background-color:#CC6600;"/>
```

ASP.NET will know how to properly override this when new colors are applied.

#### Original:

If you *had* to do this in JavaScript, You can use [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310408(v=vs.110).aspx) to send dynamic javascript code to the browser, but I suspect something else is at issue.

```cs
var script = "document.getElementById('" + Button1.ClientID + "').style.backgroundColor = 'red';";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "changecolor", script, true);
```

Comment: so where do i put the script?

Comment: That solved it.I removed all the html attributes amd made it simple by handling the colors in code-behind.Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Mash, you can leave the HTML attributes and just define BackColor to start off with (see my updated answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. It might help you. I was facing same issue but i want to change text. You can change color using this.

```
Button1.Invoke(new System.Action(() => Button1.BackColor = Color.Red));
```

Comment: Doesnt work.It says there is no defintion of 'Invoke' you are missing a namespace or directive.I added system.windows.forms directive,added a reference too.

Comment: Ok, It helped me in WinForm application. If this doesn't help you then I think you have to use JavaScript for this. It will be easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some help:

JavaScript:

```
function changeColor(e) {
    e.style.color = "red";
    return false;
}
```

ASPX:

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClientClick="return changeColor(this);" 
                runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: This will be overwritten when the page does a postback.

Comment: So here the linkbutton is the BUTTON that i am using.So it should work for button too.and where do i put the javascript code and hpow do i call it and where? I am sorry i know nothing about javascript

Comment: @Kyle instead of adding the comment while u were editing the post ..u shud hv added a ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript as u did in your post. Please be sure as to edit only the important aspects

Comment: @Himansz, You seem new here so I just want to make a distinction that is generally true sitewide.  Edits are for trivial things; comments are for important ones.  You should never add code or change someone's example while editing.  You should allow them to do it if they agree with your points.  It's *their* answer.  You can however help them improve clarity, especially in cases where they are unfamiliar with markdown or formatting conventions.  All I did was add syntax highlighting to your code block and remove a script tag that was being hidden anyway because it wasn't properly escaped.